# What's the best power armor that can be repaired without aluminum?

Tags: fallout-4

I've started putting my companions in Power Armor ever since I noticed that they don't use Fusion Cores, and I find it to be a very useful strategy.  However, I always wince whenever Preston decides a tactical charge is the best move because he's in X-01 armor and his foolishness costs me a half dozen pieces of precious aluminum.

I remember from earlier in the game that there are suits, or at least pieces of suits, that don't require aluminum to fix.  What's the best suit made out of these?

Answer (score 9):

The best combination that requires no aluminum would be a T-45 torso and T-51 helmet, legs and arms. Then the repair cost would be only 5 steel for each of the arms, legs and head with 7 steel and 1 Circuitry for the torso. The result being 32 steel and 1 Circuitry to repair everything.